# "gift" an In-App-Purchase Android

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

Is there a way to "gift" an In-App-Purchase from Google Billing to a specific account?

I put this question here because if there is a way to do it programmatically, that would be fine, but is not a must. Couldn't find anything about it in the official documentation.

The reason I want this is because one of my apps is currently in the Free and Paid versions model. But I want it to go Freemium, and I want the people who already bought the Paid version, to have everything already unlocked in the Free(now Freemium) version. Then I would just unpublish the paid.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm gonna go ahead and answer my question. There is currently no way. It may change in the future though. Thanks.

Comment: do you know about any change?

Comment: and nowadays? :)