# google play in app purchase gift first 1000 users

Tags: android

I' developing a free app where user can upgrade to the pro version using google play in app purchase. Now i want to gift the first 1000 users that they dont need to pay for the pro version of the app. Is this possible?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Google Play IAP-system it's currently not possible.

If you want to have it, you have to bypass Google Play IAP and use a custom system.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784468/gift-an-in-app-purchase-android) - nothing changed since then.

May [that post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/81517/need-to-gift-an-app-purchased-in-google-play-by-issuing-a-refund-later-how-ma) is also helpful for you.